# Ordenação de array em C -- Erro em versão float

Tags: c, array, classificação

Por algum motivo que eu não sei, quando eu mudo o tipo da minha função de int para float ela simplesmente não funciona corretamente:

```
void organizeArray(float array[], int size){
  int aux;
  for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
      if (array[j] >= array[j + 1])
      {
        aux = array[j];
        array[j] = array[j+1];
        array[j+1] = aux;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Quando eu mudo o paramêtro da função para int e entro com um array int ele funciona corretamente, mas quando uso float fica duplicando o 0 no começo da versão ordenada.
  
Entrada: float array[10] = {5, 8, 4, 7, 9, 6, 3, 0, 2, 1};
  Saída: 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 //Porque está saindo dois zeros? Alguma ideia de como consertar?

Comment: Presumindo que `size` seja o tamanho de seu array note que dentro do loop `for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)` você referencia a posição `j+1`, ou seja ao final do loop está comparando com uma posição de memória fora da área de seu array. Outra coisa que não faz sentido: este loop mais externo, com a variável `i`, você não deveria repetir apenas se ocorrer alguma troca? Suponha que seu array já esteja ordenado então não há necessidade de ficar repetindo a verificação.

Comment: Acho que tenho que estudar mais sobre o ordenação de vetores então, acho que não entendi o código ainda e nem o porque do meu problema, obrigado.